# How to apply CSS using User Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a User Script and I want to apply an external CSS to any web page using that User Script. What possibly could be done for this?

OR

Is it possible that by using JavaScript I can apply an external CSS to any web page?

I am using the following code but it is not working :

```
  var fileref=document.createElement("link");
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  fileref.setAttribute("href", "class.css");
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Comment: Where is "class.css" located? Maybe you need to provide a fully qualified URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="class.css" />
```